HP EliteDesk 800 G5 running Ubuntu Server 22.04 hangs suddenly
I have a home media server, HP EliteDesk 800 G5 running CasaOS with Docker containers (Plex and *arr)
I have two discs connected to it through USB.
But I have a problem: It hangs randomly. No more output to journalctl but it logs the reboot event that I have to do by holding power button.
journalctl -r shows (I have excluded what I think is irrelevant/duplicated info):
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000082f7fffff] usable
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed20000-0x00000000fed7ffff] reserved
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe010000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c3810000-0x00000000cc7fffff] reserved
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c380f000-0x00000000c380ffff] usable
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c378f000-0x00000000c380efff] ACPI data
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c358f000-0x00000000c378efff] ACPI NVS
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c22ab000-0x00000000c358efff] reserved
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000c22aafff] usable
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000005d000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000005c000-0x000000000005cfff] reserved
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000005bfff] usable
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-106-generic root=UUID=49c1c468-8f33-4dca-a407-2f130e797e0a ro pcie_aspm=off
May 12 14:03:52 media-server kernel: Linux version 5.15.0-106-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-017) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #116-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 09:17:56 UTC 2024 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-106.116-generic 5.15.149)
-- Boot d1de118a50364db2a6772597cfaafc95 --
May 10 23:20:32 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:20:32.04421248Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":856789,"latency_human":"856.789µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}

May 10 23:07:30 media-server casaos[947]: 消息来了，message：{"type":"ping"}
May 10 23:07:27 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:07:27.034373652Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":423014,"latency_human":"423.014µs","bytes_in":857,"bytes_out":1009}
May 10 23:07:27 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]: 2024-05-10T23:07:24.024Z        error        failed to exec shell - smartctl exec error        {"func": "service.(*diskService).SmartCTL", "file": "/home/runner/work/CasaOS-LocalStorage/CasaOS-LocalStorage/service/disk.go", "line": 149}
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]: }
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:   }
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     "protocol": "ATA"
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     "type": "sat",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     "info_name": "/dev/sdb [SAT]",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     "name": "/dev/sdb",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:   "device": {
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:   },
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     "exit_status": 2
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     ],
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:       }
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:         "severity": "information"
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:         "string": "Device is in SLEEP mode, exit(2)",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:       {
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     "messages": [
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     ],
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:       "-j"
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:       "/dev/sdb",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:       "standby",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:       "-n",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:       "-a",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:       "smartctl",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     "argv": [
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     "build_info": "(local build)",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     "platform_info": "x86_64-linux-5.15.0-105-generic",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     "svn_revision": "5155",
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     ],
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:       2
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:       7,
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     "version": [
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:   "smartctl": {
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:   ],
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     0
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:     1,
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]:   "json_format_version": [
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]: {
May 10 23:07:24 media-server casaos-local-storage[1209]: /usr/sbin/smartctl -a -n standby /dev/sdb -j
May 10 23:07:22 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:07:22.0340276Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":415194,"latency_human":"415.194µs","bytes_in":857,"bytes_out":1009}
May 10 23:07:22 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:07:17 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:07:17.04404262Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":865454,"latency_human":"865.454µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:07:17 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:07:12 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:07:12.03928355Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":377632,"latency_human":"377.632µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:07:12 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:07:07 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:07:07.030106084Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":368303,"latency_human":"368.303µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:07:07 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:07:02 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-
May 10 23:05:27 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:05:22 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:05:22.034258225Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":408322,"latency_human":"408.322µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:05:22 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:05:17 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:05:17.043849577Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":831607,"latency_human":"831.607µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:05:17 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:05:12 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:05:12.044268678Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":879245,"latency_human":"879.245µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:05:12 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:05:07 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:05:07.03617832Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":847288,"latency_human":"847.288µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:05:07 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:05:02 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:05:02.043779672Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":547463,"latency_human":"547.463µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:05:02 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:05:00 media-server casaos[947]: 消息来了，message：{"type":"ping"}
May 10 23:04:57 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:57.030521345Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":895466,"latency_human":"895.466µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:04:57 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:52 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:52.045806775Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":2576981,"latency_human":"2.576981ms","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:04:52 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:47 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:47.040944162Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":1179266,"latency_human":"1.179266ms","bytes_in":857,"bytes_out":1009}
May 10 23:04:47 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:42 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:42.030505778Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":372507,"latency_human":"372.507µs","bytes_in":857,"bytes_out":1009}
May 10 23:04:42 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:37 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:37.044284342Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":857331,"latency_human":"857.331µs","bytes_in":857,"bytes_out":1009}
May 10 23:04:37 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:32 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:32.029895872Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":375724,"latency_human":"375.724µs","bytes_in":857,"bytes_out":1009}
May 10 23:04:32 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:30 media-server casaos[947]: 消息来了，message：{"type":"ping"}
May 10 23:04:27 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:27.029825585Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":379655,"latency_human":"379.655µs","bytes_in":857,"bytes_out":1009}
May 10 23:04:27 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:22 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:22.044652215Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":981452,"latency_human":"981.452µs","bytes_in":857,"bytes_out":1009}
May 10 23:04:22 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:17 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:17.031874292Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":819409,"latency_human":"819.409µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:04:17 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:12 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:12.044076032Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":835550,"latency_human":"835.55µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:04:12 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:07 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:07.029824672Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":379381,"latency_human":"379.381µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:04:07 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:02 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:04:02.034308095Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":413222,"latency_human":"413.222µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:04:02 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1
May 10 23:04:00 media-server casaos[947]: 消息来了，message：{"type":"ping"}
May 10 23:03:57 media-server casaos-message-bus[924]: {"time":"2024-05-10T23:03:57.030882199Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:36431","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":617395,"latency_human":"617.395µs","bytes_in":859,"bytes_out":1011}
May 10 23:03:57 media-server casaos[947]: /bin/bash -c source /usr/share/casaos/shell/helper.sh ;CatNetCardState eno1


I cannot see anything strange in these logs. It always outputs this:
May 13 08:12:42 media-server casaos-message-bus[942]: {"time":"2024-05-13T08:12:42.044968818Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"127.0.0.1:41759","method":"POST","uri":"/v2/message_bus/event/casaos/casaos:system:utilization","user_agent":"Go-http-client/1.1","status":200,"error":"","latency":306066,"latency_human":"306.066µs","bytes_in":853,"bytes_out":1005}

And this:
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]: 2024-05-13T08:02:54.026Z        error        failed to exec shell - smartctl exec error        {"func": "service.(*diskService).SmartCTL", "file": "/home/runner/work/CasaOS-LocalStorage/CasaOS-LocalStorage/service/disk.go", "line": 149}
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]: }
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:   }
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     "protocol": "ATA"
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     "type": "sat",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     "info_name": "/dev/sdb [SAT]",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     "name": "/dev/sdb",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:   "device": {
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:   },
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     "exit_status": 2
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     ],
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:       }
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:         "severity": "information"
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:         "string": "Device is in SLEEP mode, exit(2)",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:       {
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     "messages": [
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     ],
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:       "-j"
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:       "/dev/sdb",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:       "standby",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:       "-n",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:       "-a",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:       "smartctl",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     "argv": [
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     "build_info": "(local build)",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     "platform_info": "x86_64-linux-5.15.0-106-generic",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     "svn_revision": "5155",
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     ],
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:       2
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:       7,
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     "version": [
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:   "smartctl": {
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:   ],
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     0
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:     1,
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]:   "json_format_version": [
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]: {
May 13 08:02:54 media-server casaos-local-storage[1193]: /usr/sbin/smartctl -a -n standby /dev/sdb -j

Where can I find the reason for the system to hang?
I don't have a display connected to it, and I have tried turning off sleep etc.
last -x  shows this:
myuser    pts/0        192.168.0.172    Mon May 13 07:38   still logged in
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.15.0-106-gener Sun May 12 14:04   still running
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-106-gener Sun May 12 14:03   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.15.0-105-gener Sun May  5 08:33 - 14:04 (7+05:31)
myuser    pts/0        192.168.0.172    Sun May  5 08:33 - 08:54  (00:21)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-105-gener Sun May  5 08:32   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.15.0-105-gener Thu May  2 15:23 - 08:33 (2+17:09)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-105-gener Thu May  2 15:22   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.15.0-105-gener Wed May  1 10:02 - 15:23 (1+05:21)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-105-gener Wed May  1 10:01   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.15.0-105-gener Fri Apr 26 06:13 - 10:02 (5+03:48)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-105-gener Fri Apr 26 06:13   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.15.0-105-gener Mon Apr 22 12:56 - 06:13 (3+17:17)
myuser    pts/0        192.168.0.172    Mon Apr 22 12:56 - 19:10  (06:14)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-105-gener Mon Apr 22 12:55   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.15.0-102-gener Tue Apr 16 13:21 - 12:56 (5+23:34)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-102-gener Tue Apr 16 13:21   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.15.0-102-gener Sun Apr 14 12:12 - 13:21 (2+01:09)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-102-gener Sun Apr 14 12:11   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.15.0-101-gener Tue Apr  2 17:32 - 12:12 (11+18:40)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-101-gener Tue Apr  2 17:31   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.15.0-101-gener Fri Mar 29 18:29 - 17:32 (3+23:02)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-101-gener Fri Mar 29 18:28   still running

